# How do I enable 1920x1080 External Display from my iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, external-display

I am trying to set up an External Display running at 1920x1080 from an iPad 4 (model MD513LL/A) through a Lightning AV Adapter. When I parse through each of the available modes, I see the following:

- 1600x900
- 1280x720
- 1024x768
- 800x600
- 640x480
- 720x480

I have tested this with three modern (1-2 years old) TVs and gotten the same results on each display, without ever seeing 1920x1080. Here is the code I am using for the external display.

EDIT: I have discovered that this is a problem ONLY with the Lightning Digital AV Adapter, not the original Digital AV Adapter.

```
if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
{
    UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *availableModeString;

    for (int i = 0; i < secondScreen.availableModes.count; i++)
    {
        availableModeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f",
        ((UIScreenMode *)[secondScreen.availableModes objectAtIndex:i]).size.width,
        ((UIScreenMode *)[secondScreen.availableModes objectAtIndex:i]).size.height];

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Available Mode" message:availableModeString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        availableModeString = nil;
    }

    // undocumented value 3 means no overscan compensation
    secondScreen.overscanCompensation = 3;

    self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 720)];
    self.secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;

    T9SecondaryScreenViewController *viewController = [[T9SecondaryScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"T9SecondaryScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.secondWindow.rootViewController = viewController;

    self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the TVs themselves don't support 1920x1080?

Comment: The TVs all support 1920x1080. They are consumer-level 40-60" LCD TVs purchased within the last two years. When the iPad is connected, the TV displays that it is showing 1920x1080 video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this adapter is not capable of 1080p.

[Source](http://9to5mac.com/2013/03/01/the-lightning-digital-av-adapter-doesnt-do-native-1080p-out-possibly-because-it-is-an-airplay-receiver/)

Comment: Yeah, I just found reference to this in the Apple Dev forums. Unbelievable. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/181189